# undefined method _path for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm running into a problem when I open a new register view.
Take a look at the error:

```
undefined method `operadors_path' for #<# 
<Class:0x0055dc5dc2ce48>:0x0055dc5dc177a0>
Did you mean?  operadores_path
operadore_path
```

And Rails complains about these line form's code:

```
<%= form_for(@operador) do |f| %>
    <% if @operador.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
             <h2>Descobrimos <%= pluralize(@operador.errors.count, "erro") %> no preenchimento do formulário :(</h2>
```

I don't understant this error because I'm not using any route like operador_path on the form's code.

Can someone help me?

My routes:

```
resources :operadores
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for(@operador) do |f| %>
    <% if @operador.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
                <h2>Descobrimos <%= pluralize(@operador.errors.count, "erro") %> no preenchimento do formulário :(</h2>

                <ul>
                <% @operador.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :user %>
        <%= f.text_field :user %>
    </div>
    </br>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :senha %>
        <%= f.text_field :senha %>
    </div>
    </br>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :operador_tipo_id %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:operador_tipo_id, @tipos_opstions_for_select, :id, :tipo) %>
    </div>
    </br>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit 2 Model and Controller.

My Model:

```
class Operador < ApplicationRecord

    attr_accessor :password

    #Relacionamento com o tipo de operador
    belongs_to :operador_tipo, optional: true

    #Validações
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_length_of :password, :is => 8
    validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required? 
    validates_presence_of :operador_tipo_id


    #Callback para encriptação de senha antes de salvar no banco
    before_save :encrypt_new_password

    #Autenticação
    #Procura e retorna o usuário se o usuario e senha estão corretos
    def self.authenticate(user, password)
        user = find_by_user(user)
        return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
    end

    #Verifica se a senha esta correta
    def authenticated?(password)
        self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
    end

    ######################### Bloco abaixo é protegido e só pode ser visto pela própria classe
    protected

    #Solicita a encriptação se a senha não estiver em branco
    def encrypt_new_password
        return if password.blank?
        self.hashed_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    #Verifica se a senha esta em branco
    def password_required?
        hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
    end

    #Efetua a encriptação
    def encrypt(string)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
    end
end
```

My Controller:

```
class OperadoresController < ApplicationController

before_action :find, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_options_for_select, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create]

  def show
    @operador = Operador.find(params[:user])

  end


  # GET /operadors/new
  def new
    @operador = Operador.new
  end

  def index
    @operadores = Operador.all
  end

  # GET /operadors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /operadors
  # POST /operadors.json
  def create
    @operador = Operador.new(operador_params)

    @operador.valid?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @operador.save
        format.html { redirect_to @operador, notice: 'Operador cadastrado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @operador }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @operador.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /operadors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /operadors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @operador.update(operador_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @operador, notice: 'Operador atualizado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @operador }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @operador.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /operadors/1
  # DELETE /operadors/1.json
  def destroy
    @operador.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to operadors_url, notice: 'Operador removido com sucesso.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def find
      @operador = Operador.find(params[:id])
   end

   def set_options_for_select
    @tipos_opstions_for_select = OperadorTipo.all
   end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def operador_params
      params.require(:operador).permit(:user, :password, :operador_tipo_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add your controller and model?

Comment: Sure @SebastiánPalma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to **@Gerry**'s answer, If you *wish not to change* the `routes` and `controller`, you can just *force Rails* to use which you are defined. You can do that with the help of `inflections`. Put the below line in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
inflect.irregular 'operador', 'operadores'
```

and restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change how `Operador` routes are set using `operadors` instead of `operadores`:

```
resources :operadors
```

And you will also need to change your controller's file name and class name:

**app/controllers/operadors_controller.rb**

```
class OperadorsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
end
```

This happens because rails defaults use plural form of model name, but this automatic *pluralization* only works with english words, for any other  word it will just add an `s` to the name (i.e. `operador` becomes `operadors`).

So, when you use `@operador` in `form_for`, rails looks for a helper using the plural form as described above, that is, `operadors_path`; but your routes specify only helpers for `operadores`, that is, `operadores_path` or, in its singular form `operadore_path` (removes the `s`).

Comment: I changed the resources to :operadors but, when I try again I received this error: uninitialized constant OperadorsController

On line codes of this file: const_getactivesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb

`names.shift if names.size > 1 && names.first.empty?
      names.inject(Object) do |constant, name|
        if constant == Object
          constant.const_get(name)
        else
          candidate = constant.const_get(name)
          next candidate if constant.const_defined?(name, false)
          next candidate unless Object.const_defined?(name)`

Comment: @JoãoHenriquePataki i forgot to specify that the controller name should also be changed; check updated answer.